# Python - Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on a program to detect faces and lock computer if there exists some unknown face on the real-time. I'm collecting 21 images first and then training the model, but there exists an error when the program stores all images in local data-set and then "my title" is the error in program at

```
ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
```

I tried installing numpy, pillow, latest opencv, opencv-python, latest python, pip3, cv2

```
def getImageWithID(path):
    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    #print(f"{imagePaths}\n")
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        faceImg = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
        #cv2.imshow('faceImg', faceImg)
        faceNp = np.array(faceImg, 'uint8')
        ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
        #print(ID)
```

I expect the program to store results in .yml file. But, program is not saving records of trainer to .yml file because it occuring an error, I hope if this error is resolved then .yml file will be created hopefully. Please help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1]` is a string `x` in your case

Comment: then how to resolve?

Comment: what is the error? Update your question with the error.

Comment: @Lomtrur my title is the error...

Comment: error is at ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1]) and "My Title of this question" is the error indicating the line of code I'm mentioning in this comment

Comment: Without knowing how you call your function or what's in `imagePaths` it's not possible to solve your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. What's inside your `int()` call is the string `x`. Why that happens can't be answered without more information

Comment: @Lomtrur can I mail you the complete code?

Comment: And you should include the stacktrace of the exception in the body of your post, that makes it easier to understand what is happening. Edit in the stacktrace and the code and people can help you

Comment: What does `path` have?

Comment: here i can't paste the complete code ... :(

Comment: @Naive dear, path has the local dataset path, where images are being stored and then the being fetched for training process

Comment: Nobody is asking you to paste the complete code. You are not ready to debug why `int()` call has string `x` and you are not ready to share what does `path` have so that people can help. StackOverflow doesn't work the way you are expecting, writing a mail. The whole purpose is to solve people's problems right here. Add `print os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1]` and update question with output.

Comment: sorry @Naive, it was my first post on StackOverflow and hopefully after reading your comment I'm not gonna use this site again ..! Thanks for your important time :)

Comment: main issue was the path that is fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What path you put into function?

You can grab paths with glob, its very easy

*recursive=True* with '**' search all folders in current, and returns list of paths with file name

```
import os
from glob import glob

files = glob('**\\*.txt', recursive=True)  # '**' is used to search in any folder, 
# '*' is wild card, use it to fit with file formats

for path in files:
    print(path)  # this is relative path
    print(os.path.abspath(path))  # this will convert relative path to absolute
```

If you want just file name, instead of this:
`ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])`

You should just use `os.path.basename(path)`

```
name = (os.path.basename(path).split('.')[0])
file_format = (os.path.basename(path).split('.')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that your path is absolute, not relative (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) for more info).
then i assume `imagePath` is `/home/user/docs/1.png` so let's see what we have:

```
>>> os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')
['1', 'png']
>>> os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1]
'png'
>>> ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'png'
```

so maybe your file name is `'somenumber.x'` ?
try modifying `[1]` to `[0]`:

```
ID = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[0])
```

Comment: as @Krug said, it depends on the path you use. I just make a guess from your output. In future if you face any problems, use console to print it out step by step like I did, then you could find out your bugs.